# Flutter Google Play version not launching as opposed to APK with the same code

Tags: flutter, apk, app-bundle

I have sent the app bundle of my app to Google Play. It has been approved. A phone has been discovered (Redmi Note 12 pro + with Xiaomi HiperOS Android 14) that has problems launching (it is installed but freezes at startup with white screen) the app downloaded from the store (AppBundle), but at the same time the app launches fine when installed from APK with the exact same codebase. What are the steps to debug?